# How to confingure nginx for domain and subdomain on AWS with ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I want to configure nginx for domain as well as sub domain on ubuntu as follows

```
mysite.in pointing to website
demo.mysite.in pointing to demo project
uat.mysite.in pointing to test project
```

My nginx conf looks like:

```
server {
listen 80 defaultserver;
listen [::]:80 defaultserver ipv6only=on;
server_name mysite.in;
location / {
root /home/amita/Website/website-v1;
try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
}

server {
listen 8087;
listen [::]:8087 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name demo.mysite.in;

location / {
root /home/amita/Project/frontend/demo/project/dist;
try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
}

server {
listen 8088;
listen [::]:8088 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name test.mysite.in;

location / {
root /home/amita/Project/frontend/test/project/dist;
try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
}
```

mysite.in , demo.mysite.in, test.mysite.in all shows up webiste.

I am unable to rectify mistake. Please help !!

Comment: Do you really want ipv6only=on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `default_server` in the first server block. The directive `default_server` applied to a server block means this server will respond to any request for which no specific server has been found to respond. It is commonly used in virtual hosting configurations.

You can also run `nginx -t` every time you edit your configuration to check if there are any new errors.

Comment: Thanks jeremielate.    nginx -t returned success.